# Jquery autocomplete with php as remote source: how to append second variable from input to source

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

I am building a form which requires autocomplete with a `php-file` as source.

The filtering is done via the `strassenliste.php`, whereby every single `keydown` does a new `php-call` with `?term=123` being attached to the URL (this is still quick enough for me).

There is one last issue to get the thing working:

I have two input fields (first is `#plz`, second is `#strasse`), where `plz` means german "`zip`" and strasse "`street`". `#strasse` is the field to be autocompleted (via `?term=...`).

When the user leaves the first input field, namely `#plz` (`onblur`), this input (`zipcode`) shall be stored in an JavaScript variable and appended to the URL `strassenliste.php` in the jQuery autocomplete code like e.g. --> source: '`strassenliste.php?plz=12345&`'.

The input of the `#strasse` then will be appended too, which already works: `?term=[input]`.

What I still don´t get working is that the parameter `zip` (followed by a `&`) is being appended to the URL `strassenliste.php`.

As a result the source in the autocomplete-code should be the URL --> `strassenliste.php?plz=12345&[term=...]`.

Here is my code that I already have:

---

**JavaScript-part:**

```
<script>
$("#plz").blur(function () {
var plz = $(this).val();
}).keyup();
var url = "strassenliste.php" + "?=&" + plz;

$(function() {
$( "#strasse" ).autocomplete({
source: url   
});

...

</script>
```

**PHP-part:**

```
$plz = $_GET['plz'];
$term = $_GET['term'];


[SOAP-Call and response]
...

foreach ($sxe->searchresults as $searchresults) {
$array[] = utf8_encode($searchresults->strasse);

sort ($array);

$strassen = "[";
foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
$strassen .= utf8_decode("\"" . ($val) . "\",");
}
$strassen .= "\"\"";

$length = strlen($strassen);
$strassen = substr($strassen, 0, $length - 3);

$strassen .= "]";

echo ($strassen);
```

---

The PHP is not the problem, this works. I tested it by giving a fix value to the variable `$plz` and simply setting the source to `strassenliste.php` in the jQuery-part.

But I still have a problem with the jQuery-Part, which is the last obstacle to get it working.

The second is that the questionmark in the autocomplete `[term =]` may not appear, since will be already appended in front of "`plz=12345`".

Does anyone have a clue?

Thank you so much for any hint!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your line `var url = "strassenliste.php" + "?=&" + plz;` can't see the variable `plz` because it's within the scope of the `blur` function.

You are also formatting the GET variables weirdly in the URL. The normal way is `myURl.php?var1=Helmut&var2=Thielicke`.

Try this:

```
    $(function() {        
        $("#plz").blur(function () {
            var plz = $(this).val(),
                url = "strassenliste.php" + "?plz=" + plz;

            $("#strasse").autocomplete({
                source: url   
            }); 
        }).keyup();
    )};
```